# Sleeping heart rate (minimum) vs resting heart rate

Tags: sleep

I'm wondering if there is a correlation between these two.

A little background: I would ideally like someone to wear a heart rate sensor all day and all night and without any explicit action from them, I want to calculate the resting heart rate. I know when they will be asleep and so I want to use the minimum heart rate from their sleeping time to work out what their waking resting heart rate is. Thanks!

EDIT: Alternative suggestions regarding working out the resting heart rate (without explicit instructions to the subject to stay still for 10 min etc.) are also welcome!

Comment: Okay, you explained the background, but what is your question?

Comment: My question is if there is a correlation between the nightly minimum heart rate and resting heart rate. If yes, can I work out the resting heart rate from the nightly minimum.